# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having a problem getting my React-Native Android app to work on a physical device. It works fine on the simulator but when deployed it does not start up. In my ANR reports I get these two errors. Any suggestions for how to debug this would be appreciated. I'm currently using the web Firebase package, but will probably switch to rnFirebase soon. I'm not sure if that could be causing the issue.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at java.lang.Runtime.load0 (Runtime.java:897)
  at java.lang.System.load (System.java:1505)
  at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom (DirectorySoSource.java:71)
  at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary (DirectorySoSource.java:42)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:299)
```

and

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Maximum call stack size exceeded., stack:
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke (BaseJavaModule.java:368)
  at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:138)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
```

Comment: whats the different between Firebase and mFirebase?

Comment: might be related to this, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814

Comment: I think that was the issue thanks

Comment: did you find the cause of your problem?